# chrome.notifications.update() not change my notification

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want my chrome extension can work as follow: once the icon is clicked, it send request to server and write some data into database; after these are done, it will popup a notification says that you track this page successfully.

However, I noticed that it would take some time before the notification pops up(because slow backend processing), so I want that once I click the icon, it firstly pops up a notification says you are tracking the page, after server request complete successfully, the notification updates to saying that you tracked this page successfully.

The problem is currently it only pops up first notification and disappears after sometime. The second notification never shows up. Can someone tell me why?

Here is some of my code related:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var n_id;
xhr.open("POST", "http://34.204.12.200:5000/track_page", true);
if (xhr.readyState !== 4) {
    var opt1 = {
        type: "basic",
        title: "price tracker",
        message: "tracking this item",
        iconUrl: "sign check.png"
    }
    chrome.notifications.create(opt1, function(notificationId) {

        n_id = notificationId;
        console.log(n_id);
    });
}

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        console.log('responseText1: ', xhr.responseText);
        if (xhr.responseText === 'success') {
            var opt2 = {
                type: "basic",
                title: "price tracker",
                message: "track this item successfully!",
                iconUrl: "sign check.png"
            }
            console.log('readyState:', xhr.readyState);
            console.log('status:', xhr.status);
            console.log(n_id);
            chrome.notifications.update(n_id, opt2);
            chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
                tabId: tab.id,
                path: {
                    "38": "icon2.png"
                }
            });
            res = 'yes';
        }
    }
}
```

and how to move code clock left in stackoverflow?

Comment: You never call `xhr.send()` so `xhr.onreadystatechange` is never triggered.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko I called, just not present it

Answer (score 0):

It happens because by default, these notifications gets disappeared after few seconds, so you can't update the notification which is vanished. In order to persist the notification, add property `requireInteraction: true` in notification option while creating notification.

Another thing is use callback function in update method for debugging purpose.